# using mamp to reindex magento indexer

Tags: macos, magento, terminal

I m trying to reindex my url rewrites for magento on local machine. I use Mac so i got terminal. when i run 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/..../shell/indexer.php: Permission denied
it says permission denied.

Comment: Please ask this question on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Trojanfoe: I dont think its really an Apple specific question... Its more magento specific regardless of environment.

Comment: Does indexer.php have execute persmissions?

Comment: @prodigitalson But you agree it doesn't belong on this site, right?

Comment: @trojanfoe: not necessarily... i mean it could go either way, here, apple.stackexchange.com, or supersuer. At the end of the day its probably a permissions issue which is an OS level thing, but it does revolve around Magento tooling... so i can see it in any of the sites. Im not going to vote to move, but i dont think you are "wrong" for doing so.

Comment: What about http://magento.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Even after changing permission i got this [link](http://screencast.com/t/UHzv6DavZmw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexer.php is not a shell script (or have shebang line). You must run it using PHP:

```
<path to php>/php <magento root>/shell/indexer.php
```

Answer (score -2):

do a

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/magento
```

in your terminal only for testing on your localhost!!!

In your live environment do this

```
find top/directory -type f -exec chmod 0644 '{}' \;
find top/directory -type d -exec chmod 0755 '{}' \;
```

Comment: never give anything slighty accessible from the outside a 777